# Split dataframe column based on specific list of words

Tags: python, regex, lambda, split, strsplit

Is it possible to split strings from a dataframe column based on a list of words?

For example: There is a dataframe with a column `Company`, each record includes the company name, a legal form, and sometimes additional information after the legal form like 'electronics'.

| Company |
| --- |
| XYZ ltd electronics |
| ABC ABC inc iron |
| AB XY Z inc |
| CD EF GHI JK llc incident |

I have list with 1500 worldwide legal form for companies (inc, ltd, ...). I would like to split the string in the dataframe column, based on this legal form list for example:

```
['gmbh', 'ltd', 'inc', 'srl', 'spa', 'co', 'sa', 'ag', 'kg', 'ab', 'spol', 'sasu', 'sas', 'pvt', 'sarl', 'gmbh & co kg', 'llc', 'ilc', 'corp', 'ltda', 'coltd', 'se', 'as', 'sp zoo', 'plc', 'pvtltd', 'og', 'gen']
```

In other words, to separate everything before and after the words in the list to new columns. This is the desired output:

| Company | Legal form | Addition |
| --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ | ltd | electronics |
| ABC ABC | inc | iron |
| AB XY Z | inc |  |
| CD EF GHI JK | llc | incident |

Note that "inc" appears in the middle, at the end, and also part of a word in the various company name examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regular expression (Regex) to filter out the legal form. Each legal form is in this format: **`\s`legalform`\s`**

`\s` means the legal form is preceded by and ended with a whitespace. Because I have appended all company names with a white space, so the legal form can be at the end as well. The data is processed in lowercase, then converted back to Title Case. So try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

legal_forms = '(\sgmbh\s|\sltd\s|\sinc\s|\ssrl\s|\sspa\s|\sco\s|\ssa\s|\sag\s|\skg\s|\sab\s|\sspol\s|\ssasu\s|\ssas\s|\spvt\s|\ssarl\s|\sgmbh\s&\sco\skg\s|\sllc\s|\silc\s|\scorp\s|\sltda\s|\scoltd\s|\sse\s|\sas\s|\ssp\szoo\s|\splc\s|\spvtltd\s|\sog\s|\sgen\s)'
df = pd.DataFrame({'Company': ['XYZ ltd electronics', 'ABC ABC inc iron', 'AB XY Z inc', 'CD EF GHI JK llc incident']}, columns=['Company'])
df['Coy']= df['Company'].apply(lambda x: [e.strip() for e in re.split(legal_forms, x.lower()+' ')])
print(df)
```

This will create a list for each company name, separated by the legal form

```
                     Company                            Coy
0        XYZ ltd electronics        [xyz, ltd, electronics]
1           ABC ABC inc iron           [abc abc, inc, iron]
2                AB XY Z inc               [ab xy z, inc, ]
3  CD EF GHI JK llc incident  [cd ef ghi jk, llc, incident]
```

After that you can split them into 3 separate columns:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df['Coy'].tolist(), columns=['Company', 'Legal form', 'Addition'])
for col in df1.columns:
    df1[col] = df1[col].str.title()
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
        Company Legal form     Addition
0           Xyz        Ltd  Electronics
1       Abc Abc        Inc         Iron
2       Ab Xy Z        Inc             
3  Cd Ef Ghi Jk        Llc     Incident
```

Comment: I edited the company names. If the company names would contain only one word this should work of course but in my case it‘s not that easy

Comment: sure.. I've edited the answer, this time using regular expression, pls have a look :-)

Comment: Thank you again for your anwser but the list contains over 1500 legal world wide forms which would be very exhausting to enter them manually

Comment: would you copy-paste the list of legal forms here, so that I can format them into the code

Comment: Unfortunately I can not insert so many words here, so I take only an excerpt and can then apply it to the whole list itself.

Comment: 'gmbh', 'ltd', 'inc', 'srl', 'spa', 'co', 'sa', 'ag', 'kg', 'ab', 'spol', 'sasu', 'sas', 'pvt', 'sarl', 'gmbh & co kg', 'llc', 'ilc', 'corp', 'ltda', 'coltd', 'se', 'as', 'sp zoo', 'plc', 'pvtltd', 'og', 'gen'

Comment: sure.. I've edited the answer again. Please note that white space is `\s` in regex, and these legal forms are separated by `|` which means 'or'

Comment: hi @hazen23 is the code able to resolve your question?

Comment: Hi @perpetualstudent, I can work with that. I was hoping that I wouldn't have to manually type out the legal forms. Nevertheless it works - Thank you very much!

Comment: do you have the list of legal forms in pdf or text format? I can help you create the python list using some automation

Comment: I can help if you allow. But if you're trying it yourself, you could try text replace by Control+H in a text editor

Comment: you could share the list via dropbox or googleDrive, etc

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are just trying to string split after spaces you could try something like this:

```
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({'Company': ['XYZ ltd electronics', 'ABC ABC inc iron', 'AB XY Z inc', 'CD EF GHI JK llc chicago']}, columns=['Company'])
df['Addition'] = df['Company'].apply(lambda x: re.split('(ltd|inc|llc)', x))
print(df)

                    Company                        Addition
0       XYZ ltd electronics       [XYZ , ltd,  electronics]
1          ABC ABC inc iron          [ABC ABC , inc,  iron]
2               AB XY Z inc               [AB XY Z , inc, ]
3  CD EF GHI JK llc chicago  [CD EF GHI JK , llc,  chicago]
```

Comment: I edited the company names. If the company names would contain only one word this should work of course but in my case it‘s not that easy

Comment: upvoted, the code should work now